# How to hide tabular inline if checkbox is selected

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django

I want to hide the Choices form if the checkbox is not selected, I've tried solving this using jquery but I can't seem to get it working...

[Image of what i'm trying to hide and the checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuRgX.png)

asset_admin.js

```
console.log(django.jQuery('#id_is_multiple_choice'))
django.jQuery('#id_is_multiple_choice').change(function(){
if(django.jQuery("#id_is_multiple_choice").is(':checked'))
    {
        django.jQuery(".js-inline-admin-formset inline-group").show();
        console.log('showing element');
    }else
    {
        django.jQuery(".js-inline-admin-formset inline-group").hide();
        console.log('hiding element');
    }
});
```

The initial console.log prints out

```
jQuery.fn.init {}
```

and none of the other console.logs print so for some reason the if statement isn't being executed... This is the checkbox in html

```
<div class="checkbox-row">     

<input type="checkbox" name="is_multiple_choice" id="id_is_multiple_choice" checked><label class="vCheckboxLabel" for="id_is_multiple_choice">Is the question multiple choice?</label>

</div>
```

Here is my admin.py although I doubt this has anything to do with my issue

```
class ChoiceTabularInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Choice

    class Media:
        js = ('/staticfiles/admin/js/assets_admin.js',
              '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js',
              )
```

Comment: If an error occurs the process will die. That's why you see no other console.log() statements after. And in the first line to me it looks like theres a typo.

Comment: @Thielicious ah man good eye, fixed the typo. However, when I check the checkbox nothing happens and the console.logs within the if statement do not execute so something in my JS is still messed up.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$("#id_is_multiple_choice").attr("checked") ? alert("Checked") : alert("Unchecked");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkbox-row">     

    <input type="checkbox" name="is_multiple_choice" id="id_is_multiple_choice"><label class="vCheckboxLabel" for="id_is_multiple_choice">Is the question multiple choice?</label>

    </div>
```